# how to solve this error in oracle and in mysql

Tags: mysql, oracle

i have this problem in my where clause which sql was telling that this is invalid sql statement. rowname is datetime. there is something wrong with my if statement which i cant figure out. hope you guys can help me... thanks

note: i manage to change my code in much clearer version hope you guys can help me (i have a select query in two tables)

where

```
                last_update_date between

                    IF  tbl1.last_update_date is not null

                    THEN

                        max(tbl1.last_update_date)

                    ELSE

                        min(tbl2.last_update_date)

                    END IF;

                and 
                    sysdate
```

Comment: Is your column really named "rowname" ?

Comment: You should use `COALESCE()`, it returns the first non-NULL argument

Comment: Inline if statements should also work (At least in mysql. I don't use $Oracle$). Simple example, `IF(value > 100, 100, value)`

Answer (score 0):

`If` is not part of the syntax of a `select` statement.  It is part of the language at a higher level.  So, you cannot include it in a `where` statement.  You want something like:

```
WHERE rowname >= coalesce((select max(rowname) from tbl1), (select min(rowname) from tbl2), rowname)) and
                 sysdate
```

Also, `sysdate` is an Oracle definition.  MySQL would typically use `now()`.  They both might support the ANSI standard `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: the second line should be `rowname <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` -- you haven't quite translated the BETWEEN from the original

Comment: Also, the SQL standard is from ISO, not ANSI.

Comment: i want to do it from both mysql and in oracle, the problem is i want to put a condition in my where clause which the result would be the min time if the ROWNAME is null else max time